# Reverse certain rows in N by 2 array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an N by 2 array like this one:

```
[[9 1]
 [0 5]
 [6 3]
 [2 4]
 [3 5]
 [4 1]
 [2 7]
 [6 8]
 [7 9]
 [8 0]]
```

After I make a search in this matrix, I return some indices where the rows must be permuted.

In my case, I had `w=[1 0 9 8 7]`.

I use this code to permute the 2 columns **ONLY** on selected rows.

```
        for x in w:
            self.nodes[x] = roll (self.nodes[x], 1)
```

The result is correct like this:

```
[[1 9]  *
 [5 0]  *
 [6 3]
 [2 4]
 [3 5]
 [4 1]
 [2 7]
 [8 6]  *
 [9 7]  *
 [0 8]] *
```

The starred rows were correctly permuted.

I want to know if there is a ***ONE-LINER*** numpy expression that does all this trick.

The important fact here is the speed of the operation.

Comment: What if there's a two-line expression which is ten times faster?  You're not interested?

Comment: I am interested, but I suspected that a oneliner that does not contain python expressions is made by a single numpy function (as it happened to discover), and this numpy is faster than python.

Comment: But if you know something as convenient as 2 of these answers , write here ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works by applying the roll to a copy of `a` only at indices `w` and then setting those in the original `a` with the rolled values:

```py
a[w] = np.roll(a[w], 1, axis=1)
```

Someone had an answer (I think @seberg, but it's now deleted) that showed that for two columns rolling is equivalent to reversing, you do not actually need to `roll`, and can use the reversing by index trick as so:

```py
a[w] = a[w, ::-1]
```

For large arrays, the timing is similar. For shorter arrays, the `roll` solution is slower. Here is the timing.

```py
N = 10
a = np.arange(N*2).reshape(-1,2)
w = np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=N/2, replace=False)

timeit a[w] = np.roll(a[w],1,1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.2 µs per loop

timeit a[w] = a[w, ::-1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.07 µs per loop

N = 1000
a = np.arange(N*2).reshape(-1,2)
w = np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=N/2, replace=False)

timeit a[w] = np.roll(a[w],1,1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 113 µs per loop

timeit a[w] = a[w, ::-1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 93.6 µs per loop

N = 100000
a = np.arange(N*2).reshape(-1,2)
w = np.random.choice(np.arange(N), size=N/2, replace=False)

timeit a[w] = np.roll(a[w],1,1)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop

timeit a[w] = a[w, ::-1]
100 loops, best of 3: 9.63 ms per loop
```

Comment: in my case , as I wrote in title, reversing is similar to shifting.

Comment: Yes, I am working here with a simple permutation , not with complicated data structures, so 2 columns are enough to encode the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.nodes[w] = np.asarray(map(lambda x: np.roll(x,1), self.nodes[w]))
```

Comment: I am afraid that even if this is oneliner, it works slower than the code I wrote ;).